# Example of knot that "becomes unknotted in a different 3-manifold"?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, knot-theory

Suppose I had a knot $K \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, and an open ball $U$ inside a $3$-manifold $M$. If I now consider $K \subset U$ (via some homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $U$), could it be possible that $K$ is unknotted in $M$? That is to say, $K$ becomes isotopic to the unknot in $U$; somehow "using the additional geometry that $M$ provides to make unknotting easier"? If so, are there any easy examples I can write down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.  Let $S$ be the boundary of the closure of $U$, which is a $2$-sphere in $M$.  If $K$ is unknotted, that means there is an embedded disk $D\subset M$ whose boundary is $K$.  We can isotope $D$ so that it intersects $S$ transversely.  The intersection $D\cap S$ is a disjoint union of circles.  Let's assume $D$ is chosen to minimize the number of circles in this intersection.  If there is a circle, then there is one that bounds a disk $D'\subset S$ whose interior contains none of these circles.  Compressing $D$ along $D'$ (and then throwing away any $2$-sphere components) yields a new disk whose boundary is $K$ and which intersects $S$ in *fewer* circles, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $D\subset U$, and $K$ is an "unknot in $\mathbb{R}^3$."

Comment: thanks! I think the only point I'm stuck on is why an isotopy of K to an unknot guarentees that there is a disk whose boundary is K, are there any references I can look at for this? The sources I found talking about this (e.g. https://web.math.ucsb.edu/~mgscharl/papers/knottheory.pdf, theorem 2) seem to imply this only works in S^3 (and also don't provide a proof), but I guess it works in general?

Comment: Usually the definition of an unknot is a knot which is isotopic to the standard unknot (say, the unit circle in the XY plane), and the standard unknot bounds the unit disk.  Now, run the ambient isotopy in reverse to get your original knot while dragging this unit disk along: you get a disk whose boundary is $K$.  A key thing in the theory of knots is isotopy extension: an isotopy of tame embeddings of a circle into a $3$-manifold extends to an isotopy of the $3$-manifold itself, called an *ambient isotopy*.  This ambient isotopy is what's dragging the disk along.

Comment: In that source, note that the author is just focusing on knots in $S^3$, but it still goes for other $3$-manifolds.  Actually, tempering "usually" in my previous comment, I'd say it's rather common to say that an unknot is a knot that bounds a disk.  It's not that hard to see that any two such knots are isotopic, justifying calling them unknots.  (A regular neighborhood of the disk is a ball containing an "$\mathbb{R}^3$ unknot", and every ball in a connected $3$-manifold is isotopic to every other.)